# How to programmatically code a block to show taxonomy vocabulary as an unordered list?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, routes

I'm trying to build a menu using a taxonomy vocabulary with its hierarchical structure. 
I don't want to use any module to do it.

In this page I see that I can grab the terms for a given vocabulary and do it programmatically http://drupal.org/node/113651

But I need some help to star coding it.

I have a Taxonomy called: Products (the tid is : 2)

Products has the following terms and hierarchical structure:

```
--Cars
----Volvo
----Ford
--Games
----Football
----Rugby
----Videogames
------Pacman
------Call of Duty
```

PHP CODE to generate:

```
<ul>
    <li>Cars
        <ul>
            <li>Volvo</li>
            <li>Ford</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Games
        <ul>
            <li> Football </li>
            <li> Rugby </li>
            <li>Cars
                <ul>
                    <li> Pacman </li>
                    <li>Call of Duty</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's something I have put together for myself in the past. I posted the code on the Drupal [taxonomy_get_tree()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_get_tree/7/#comment-22553) API page where you can get a copy for yourself. The core part of the code is usable with Drupal 6 as well (some smaller modifications are needed to make it work though).